# Date to Zodiac sign and format date

Tags: php, date-format

Ok I have some code, gleaned from the internet. So this is the case and what I am trying to acheive.

Ok Page, user enters Birthday ( not Birthdate ) So we have the data in format dd/mm saved to database, example: 30/07 to represent 30 July )

So next page user goes to , I want to format the date correctly to match what I am trying to acheieve, add corresponding ordinal ( but remove the - between dd and mm ) and not echo the yy because we never got that information in the first place.

Essentially, if when user hits this page, we know the dd and mm , I am happy to add current year as the yy ( but not to fetch yy from the db ) but instead supply it adhoc.

The script below, is from internet and takes into account leap years, but need help. I cannot just remove the year, as this gives false results ( presumably because of strtotime function )But when user added their Birthday , we did not grab the year, because we do not need it.

Code:

```
<?php
function getStarSign($date="")
{
$zodiac[356] = "Capricorn";
$zodiac[326] = "Sagittarius";
$zodiac[296] = "Scorpio";
$zodiac[266] = "Libra";
$zodiac[235] = "Virgo";
$zodiac[203] = "Leo";
$zodiac[172] = "Cancer";
$zodiac[140] = "Gemini";
$zodiac[111] = "Taurus";
$zodiac[78]  = "Aries";
$zodiac[51]  = "Pisces";
$zodiac[20]  = "Aquarius";
$zodiac[0]   = "Capricorn";
if (!$date) $date = time();
$dayOfTheYear = date("z",$date);
$isLeapYear = date("L",$date);
if ($isLeapYear && ($dayOfTheYear > 59)) $dayOfTheYear = $dayOfTheYear - 1;
foreach($zodiac as $day => $sign) if ($dayOfTheYear > $day) break;
return $sign;
}
$myBday = "2013-07-30"; // this needs to be in English Australian format not American English format but do not need year
$AuEnBday = date("dS-F-Y", strtotime($myBday)); // this switches the date from USA to AU date format but do not need year
?>
```

The above echoes:Leo 30th-July-2013

I want to echo : Leo 30th July ( the year bit can be a var on page somehow but NOT from db )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// One more time!
$myBday = date("Y") . "-07-30"; // 2013-07-30

// Two digit year
$myBday2 = date("y") . "-07-30"; // 13-07-30
```

Comment: Yeah that much I could do, but the var $myBday must have yy in. Otherwise we get crappy results, so wondered if we could replace 2013 with get current year.

Comment: All you need to do is add the lowercase `y` to the formatting string

Comment: Sorry perhaps I am confusing you. $myBday must be formatted like yy-dd-mm ( the yy ) I would like to declare on this page, by means of using a var. But in $AuEnBday I do not want to echo the year at all

Comment: Let me know if my new answer is what you're looking for

Comment: No sorry, so example: when user hits this page we fetch from database dd and mm ( we do not know the yy ) so would need to declare yy somehom using something as simple as $curYear = date('Y'); but would need to format the declaration in $myBday = "2013-07-30"; along the lines of $myBday = "Y-07-30"; but that doesnt work. Does that make sense ?

Comment: actually, strike that. You may have hit the nail on the head... bear with me

Comment: My bad, works perfect thanks. No idea why I didnt get it the first time, perhaps I was looking at cached version. Grrr but works great many thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!